# Setting Headers for GET Request - Angular 2 Observable/Promise

Tags: angular, get, promise, http-headers, observable

I am currently getting an `Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` error when using HTTP GET to my Cloudant/NoSQL database.

I am aware that setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` would allow for GET requests from `localhost`, however I see no documentation from Angular 2 specifically for setting headers.

```
async getData(): Promise<IPost[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._postUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

`IPost[]` is the object that will be returned after `extractData()` is executed.

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to set this header on the server, not within the Angular application.

Comment: Found it, hidden deep in the settings of the database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this when I want to call REST APIs.  data is the request object you send.

```
 const HEADERS = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

     this.http.post(ENDPOINT, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: HEADERS})
          .map(this.extractData)
          .subscribe(
            payload => {
                           //do some operation or set values with payload
                        }
          );
```

This is for the post call. If you want to work with a GET call, you don't have to set any headers on the angular 2 side. It's only required on the backend side to allow the requests for your localhost / particular machine.